# How OSGi solves the task of casting bundle-defined classes to rt.jar-defined classes?

Tags: java, osgi, concept

How OSGi solves the problem<sup>1</sup> of casting classes which were loaded from bundles with OSGi custom classloader to classes loaded from rt.jar? Does rt.jar loaded with custom classloader too, instead of system classloader?

**UPD1**

It appears that i canot load most parts of rt.jar with custom classloader, because of the following code in the ClassLoader.java:

```
private ProtectionDomain preDefineClass(String name, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain) {
    ...
    if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
        throw new SecurityException("Prohibited package name: " +
        name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
    }
    ...
}
```

[1] the problem is in the following: classes loaded with different classloaders are treated by jvm as entirely different ones even if their byte-code is exactly the same, so when, for example, we have class `rt.jar!/SomeClass` and derived it inside of `bundle.jar!/SomeClassChild`, we cannot cast `SomeClassChild` to `SomeClass` if they were loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: Very interesting. Can you provide some sort of sample application to reproduce the problem?

Comment: As a general principle, OSGi and custom classloaders won't play well together, unless the scope of the custom classloader is pretty narrow. Where and why is the custom class loader being used?

Comment: @HollyCummins i am not trying to make OSGi and my custom classloaders play together, i am trying to write own classloader which will work on same principle as OSGi; some kind of own tiny implementation of subset of OSGi, without actual OSGi involved.

Comment: I see. What you'll want to do, both for memory efficiency and to avoid the class incompatibility issues you're seeing, is delegate wherever possible to a class's 'natural' classloader. This is what OSGi does - a class is only loaded by multiple classloaders if the binaries are packaged in multiple jars.

Comment: I'd also add that you may find simply making use of OSGi the best option, since it's very mature and also lightweight enough to be used in embedded systems. And, as you're discovering, writing classloaders is hard. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such problem in Java. Certainly not as stated in the question. It is true that classes with the same name loaded by different classloaders are never treated as the same class, but from this it does not follow that a superclass has to be loaded by the same classloader as a subclass.

Actually since all java.* classes, including Object, come from the bootstrap classloader and no user class in an application is loaded by the bootstrap classloader, it would be impossible to even cast anything to Object, ever, way before OSGi came into the picture.

Answer (score 1):

- java.* classes are special ... The Java specification requires all classes that start with 'java.' to be loaded from the boot class path for security reasons.
- Other classes, well packages, from rt.jar are exported by the framework itself. All frameworks have a set of defaults but there are properties that allows you to extend these defaults (org.osgi.framework.system.packages[.extra]). The framework will load classes in these packages either from the classloader that loaded the framework or from the boot class loader based on a launch property.

The magic is that the OSGi framework wires all those packages together in a mesh of classloaders that ensures that each bundle sees a consistent class space free of conflicts even if multiple class loaders can load the same class name. Therefore, class cast exceptions cannot happen in OSGi with proper metadata and without class loading hacks.

If two bundles are bound to different class loaders for the same package name then the OSGi framework ensures that these bundles cannot see each other since they then reside in different class spaces.